# Nginx HTTPS fails, but node.js https works

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, https

Nginx http works fine, but https fails. So, I build a nodejs https server. It works, which means the operation system (CentOS 6.8) is OK.

What's the problem with Nginx?

nginx -V

```
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0
built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-debug --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --with-ld-opt=' -Wl,-E'
```

nginx.conf

```
user  www;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$request_time $remote_addr $remote_user [$time_local] $http_host "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';


    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

website.com.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name website.com;
    ssl on;
    index index.html index.htm;

    ssl_certificate   certs/website.com/214523442680009.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  certs/website.com/214523442680009.key;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;  

    root "/var/www/website/";


        access_log /var/log/nginx/website.com-access.log main;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/website.com-error.log error;
}
```

The weird thing is that there is no any log, neither access nor error log. It seems that the request has been blocked even before it reaches Nginx. But this doesn't make sense since the nodejs server works fine.

telnet

```
vagrant@homestead:/htdocs$ telnet website.com 443
Trying xx.xx.xxx.x...
Connected to website.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

netstat

```
[root@iZ23foxgunwZ ~]# netstat -nap | grep :443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9932/nginx
```

The nodejs script

```
var https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

https.createServer({
host: 'deyuapi.com',   
key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/certs/website.com/214523442680009.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/certs/website.com/214523442680009.pem')
}, function (request, response) {

    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(443);
```

It's not my first time to set up ssl with Nginx. But this situation confuses me a lot.

Any advise will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you intend to use the nginx for? You have no `location` directive setup within the `server`.

Comment: I agree with @hcheung you are not serving anything. There is no index file to be served (in case of static files), nor proxying, and nothing. Your problem is that nginx does not know what to do with your request

Answer (score 0):

you must define a location, this makes nginx works as reverse proxy

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://your_server_ip:your_port;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

Comment: I don't want nginx to work as reverse proxy.  My config works fine in http, but fails in https.